# OpenGL perspective matrix to DirectX matrix?

Tags: c++, directx, glm-math

I am converting my OpenGL engine to DirectX11. I used GLM in OpenGL, and will continue in Directx if possible. One problem I have however is constructing the perspective matrix using the `glm::perspective`

OpenGL maps [-1, 1] whereas DirectX maps [0, 1]. Is there any easy fix for this? I'd rather not switch math library just because of this.

Comment: Just build your own perspective matrix. Check this out: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205350(v=vs.85).aspx This is a built in function for Direct3D/X for constructing the matrix

Comment: Actually I recommend avoiding using legacy D3DXMath. Use [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx).

Comment: Oh yes thats right. I have done OpenGL more recently. Used to old directx.

Answer (score 0):

You either use [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx)'s XMMatrixPerspectiveFovRH (for right-handed view systems) or XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH (for left-handed setups). With the Direct3D 9 legacy fixed-function pipeline you have to use LH. For programmable shaders, it's up to you by DirectX apps are often LH, while OpenGL apps are often RH. See the [DirectXMath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729728.aspx) programmer's guide for more on this.

If using the legacy DirectX SDK without the Windows 8.0 SDK or Windows 8.1 SDK, you can make use of [XNAMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/22/xna-math-version-2-05-smoothing-the-transition-to-directxmath.aspx) which is very similar to DirectXMath.